# How to take input from different lines in a list of Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, input, line

I want list from the user input from different lines WITHOUT knowing the number of lines.

I tried something and don't know how to replace value of 'n' from below code to get input from different WITHOUT requesting number of line from user.

arr = [ int(input()) for i in range(n)]

Comment: looks like you need a `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

use a `while True` loop and keep checking for a special character or string to break the loop.

```py
myList = list()
while True:
    inp = input('input > ')
    if inp == '-1': # using -1 to break loop, you could put your choice
        break
    myList.append(inp)
```

Comment: i used your code in codeChef python3 compiler with custom input as: 
1
2
3
4
8
7
5
  and it showed error.....   
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 3, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line  

and my code was..............
myList = list()
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == '-1':
        break
    myList.append(inp)
print(myList)

Comment: it seems like you are trying to take all input at once and want it to be stored as list of integers. if that is the case use scan the input as a string and split and convert to int as shown below:

Comment: sorry missed to put code: 

```
inp = input()

inList = [int(x.strip()) for x in inp.split()]

```

Comment: Your code is still taking only first number.. and not the rest of the numbers... Why.?

Comment: My input is like 1 \n 2 \n 3 \4 \5.  Because here new line is not showing in comment box.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is a solution that I found..
it take input as:
1
2
3
4
8
7
5
6
and output as:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6]
My code is here....
arr = []
while True:
    try:
        line = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
    arr.append(line)
arr = list(map(int, arr)) 
print(arr)
```